# Perl Regex segregating text chunks

Tags: regex, perl

I have a long text file like:

```
COMPONENT;SCALAR;VALUE
point1/point2 - Value Value Value
point1/point2 - Value Value Value
point1/point2 - Value Value Value
point1/point2 - Value Value Value
point1/point2 - Value Value Value
point1/point2 - Value Value Value
point1/point2 - Value Value Value

COMPONENT;SCALAR;VALUE
point3/point4 - Value Value Value
point3/point4 - Value Value Value
point3/point4 - Value Value Value
point3/point4 - Value Value Value
point3/point4 - Value Value Value
point3/point4 - Value Value Value
point3/point4 - Value Value Value
```

Now I have already extracted all the unique values of 'point3/point4' type of values .. Now what I have to do is to extract the whole data chunk .. e.g From COMPONENT;SCALAR ----> \n\n (There are two new lines at end of block). Now what I tried to do is

```
string =~ /(COMPO\S\spoint1\/point2)(.+?)(COMP)/s;
print $2;
```

but it doesn't work. The match should match only till the first '\n\n'  and not be greedy to capture max. Any one liner would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using a perl one liner.

```
perl -00 -ne 'print if m{point1/point2};' data.txt
```

The only trick is from [`perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) using `-00` for paragraph mode.